# How to iterate over a table and print the results from the first 10 rows with python and selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Using selenium webdriver and python I am able to locate the search cell and search to return results however I want to print the results from the first 10 rows returned (minus the title row).

The site I am using is: http://www.hoovers.com/company-information/company-search.html?term=simon  for example as a search term.

I have been searching for a while and have tried many things including xpaths and most error out. This is the closest I've come so far:

```
for row in mydriver.find_elements_by_class_name('cmp-company-directory'):
        cell = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")[0]
        print(cell.text)
```

However it only returns the first row and will not iterate through the table.  Any tips?
TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below Xpath it will traverse through table and print first 10 rows.

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='clear data-table sortable-header dashed-table-tr alternate-rows']//tr/td")
counter=1
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
    counter+=1
    if counter==50:
        break
```

OutPut:

```
Simon Property Group, Inc.
Indianapolis, IN, United States
$5538.64M
See Details

SIMON & SCHUSTER (UK) LIMITED
London, London, England
$60.39M
See Details

SIMON JERSEY GROUP LIMITED
Accrington, Lancashire, England

See Details

Simon Worldwide, Inc.
Irvine, CA, United States
$0.0M
See Details

Simon Property Group, L.P.
Indianapolis, IN, United States
$5538.64M
See Details

Günter Simon e.K. Inh. Carmen Simon
Ravensburg, Baden-Württemberg, Germany

See Details

Simon e Simon Servicos Odontologicos Ltda
Vere, Parana, Brazil

See Details

Simon Comercial e Industrial Ltda Em Recuperacao Judicial
Aparecida De Goiania, Goias, Brazil

See Details

Simon Levelt B.V.
Haarlem, Noord-Holland, The Netherlands

See Details

SIMON SAU
Barcelona, Barcelona, Spain
$115.95M
See Details
```

If you want to print only first 10 rows of company name try this.

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='clear data-table sortable-header dashed-table-tr alternate-rows']//tr/td[@class='company_name']")
counter=0
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
    counter+=1
    if counter==10:
        break
```

OutPut:-

```
Simon Property Group, Inc.
SIMON & SCHUSTER (UK) LIMITED
SIMON JERSEY GROUP LIMITED
Simon Worldwide, Inc.
Simon Property Group, L.P.
Günter Simon e.K. Inh. Carmen Simon
Simon e Simon Servicos Odontologicos Ltda
Simon Comercial e Industrial Ltda Em Recuperacao Judicial
Simon Levelt B.V.
```

Let me know if this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To print the *Company Names* excluding the title row you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([company_name.get_attribute("innerHTML") for company_name in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.cmp-company-directory table td.company_name>a")))])
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([company_name.get_attribute("innerHTML") for company_name in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cmp-company-directory']//table//td[@class='company_name']/a")))])
  ```

To print the first 10 *Company Names* excluding the title row you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located` and then you have to use **`[:10]`** to limit the list to **10** elements and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([company_name.text for company_name in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.cmp-company-directory table td.company_name>a")))[:10]])
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([company_name.text for company_name in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cmp-company-directory']//table//td[@class='company_name']/a")))[:10]])
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```